# Override onConfigurationChanged while maintaining portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-configchanges, onconfigurationchanged

How do I detect landscape mode while maintaining my layouts in portrait mode?

I have an activity which maintains the portrait mode irrespective of actual mobile orientation. I can do this by adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to my activity configuration in manifest.

However, I want to detect screenOrientation while maintaining the activity in portrait.

I have tried with following code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        recordConfigChanges(newConfig);     // Performs some variable changes or similar
    }
    // Maintain activity in portrait mode itself
    Configuration customConfig = newConfig;
    customConfig.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    super.onConfigurationChanged(customConfig);
}
```

The above code does not maintain portrait, it rotates the UI to landscape mode. 
Re-iterating the original question, how do I detect landscape mode while maintaining my layouts in portrait mode?

Comment: I tried few snippets but the issue is we can't get callback of `onConfigurationChanged` if we set or request portrait layout using manifest or runtime. We need something like observer which observe phone configuration changes and trigger event when orientation changed.

Comment: @BipinVayalu - yes, you are right. I am looking for that observer or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **CustomOrientationEventListener** without affect actual Orientation change

in your activity

```
  ...
  private CustomOrientationEventListener customOrientationEventListener;
  ...

 customOrientationEventListener = new CustomOrientationEventListener(mContext) {
        @Override
        public void onSimpleOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
       }
 };

 customOrientationEventListener.enable();
```

standalone class **CustomOrientationEventListener**

```
public abstract class CustomOrientationEventListener extends OrientationEventListener {
private String TAG="CustomOrientation";
private static final int CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
private volatile int defaultScreenOrientation = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
private int prevOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
private Context ctx;
private final int ROTATION_O    = 1;
private final int ROTATION_90   = 2;
private final int ROTATION_180  = 3;
private final int ROTATION_270  = 4;

private int rotation = 0;
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

public CustomOrientationEventListener(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ctx = context;
}

public CustomOrientationEventListener(Context context, int rate) {
    super(context, rate);
    ctx = context;
}

@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(final int orientation) {
    //return if auto rotate disabled. should rotate if auto rotate enabled only
    if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 0) // 0 = Auto Rotate Disabled
    return;
    int currentOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
    if (orientation >= 340 || orientation < 20 && rotation != ROTATION_O) {
        currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
        rotation = ROTATION_O;

    } else if (orientation >= 70 && orientation < 110 && rotation != ROTATION_90) {
        currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
        rotation = ROTATION_90;

    } else if (orientation >= 160 && orientation < 200 && rotation != ROTATION_180) {
        currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
        rotation = ROTATION_180;

    } else if (orientation >= 250 && orientation < 290 && rotation != ROTATION_270) {
        currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
        rotation = ROTATION_270;
    }

    if (prevOrientation != currentOrientation
            && orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
        prevOrientation = currentOrientation;
        if (currentOrientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN)
            reportOrientationChanged(currentOrientation);
    }

}

private void reportOrientationChanged(final int currentOrientation) {

    int defaultOrientation = getDeviceDefaultOrientation();
    int orthogonalOrientation = defaultOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            : Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    int toReportOrientation;

    if (currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
        toReportOrientation = defaultOrientation;
    else
        toReportOrientation = orthogonalOrientation;

    onSimpleOrientationChanged(toReportOrientation);
}

/**
 * Must determine what is default device orientation (some tablets can have
 * default landscape). Must be initialized when device orientation is
 * defined.
 *
 * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or
 *         {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
 */
private int getDeviceDefaultOrientation() {
    if (defaultScreenOrientation == CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
        lock.lock();
        defaultScreenOrientation = initDeviceDefaultOrientation(ctx);
        lock.unlock();
    }
    return defaultScreenOrientation;
}

/**
 * Provides device default orientation
 *
 * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or
 *         {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
 */
private int initDeviceDefaultOrientation(Context context) {

    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    boolean isLand = config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    boolean isDefaultAxis = rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180;

    int result = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    if ((isDefaultAxis && isLand) || (!isDefaultAxis && !isLand)) {
        result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    } else {
        result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Fires when orientation changes from landscape to portrait and vice versa.
 *
 * @param orientation
 *            value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or
 *            {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
 */
public abstract void onSimpleOrientationChanged(int orientation);

}
```

Comment: Very interesting. How is the `customOrientationEventListener` bound to the activity or context? Don't we need to do something like `this.setOrientationEventListener`?

Comment: either you can extend class and onverride it `onSimpleOrientationChanged` or you can use as anonymous class which you can see in answer!

Comment: @KishoreJethava i tried your code as per your example but can't get `onSimpleOrientationChanged` callback. Can you show how we bound listener?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add  to enable listener `customOrientationEventListener.enable();` see updated answer!

Comment: With minor changes in your `onOrientationChanged`, your solution worked perfect. Amazing answer, thank you :)